# can get it work htpasswd

Tags: apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

i can get the .htpasswd to work with .htaccess

I have the following lines in htacess

```
<Files ".htaccess">
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
AuthUserFile /var/www/example/.htpasswd
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user  

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php/$1



and htpasswd look as it follows

user:passw
<Files ".htpasswd">
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

I'm trying to log in but without success
apache error.log tells
 "/": Password Mismatch but I have been checking couple of times everything is okay with it.

Comment: You can find the answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229656/password-protecting-a-directory-and-all-of-its-subfolders-using-htaccess/43831765#43831765

Answer (score 0, accepted):

password are manipulated using htpasswd utility

see: http://linux.die.net/man/1/htpasswd

Your case can be:

```
htpasswd -c /var/www/example/.htpasswd user
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and generate passwords using the site: [htpasswd-generator](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/) and also put the file outside the web root directory of the site not inside it.