# How to makeup password in .htpasswd file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, webserver, .htpasswd

Here I want to protect a directory of a website which require a username and password to access..

I created .htaccess file in same directory..

```
 AuthName "Member's Area Name"
 AuthUserFile /path/to/password/file/.htpasswd
 AuthType Basic
 require valid-user
```

and here my .htpasswd file in the same directory

```
username:encryptedpassword
fred_smith:oCF9Pam/MXJg2
```

So my problem is  how to setup my own custom password in the above field `'encryptedpassord'` as I read we cannot just make up the password, on Unix/Linux servers they must be encrypted by the server, on Windows servers you do just use a plain text password as Windows does not offer any encryption methods

IS THERE ANY METHOD TO SET OWN CUSTOM PASSWORD?

Comment: This question is answered here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229656/password-protecting-a-directory-and-all-of-its-subfolders-using-htaccess/43831765#43831765

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use htpasswd command to create a new entry in that file.

```
htpasswd /path/to/password/file/.htpasswd john
```

will ask you for the password of john, then will create a user entry for it.

Comment: On any shell of the system. Are you using a linux or a windows machine?