# how to check values entered in the form with valuesin the .txt file in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have created HTML form asking for username and password and I have one .txt file containing many username and password.
I need to check wheather the entered username and password is present in .txt file using javascript.

Please help me out.

Comment: Security at it's finest :P . Please post what you've tried thus far, and then we can better help you out.

Comment: I sort of don't even want to help, in case this might make it into some production code somewhere.

Comment: I am new to javascript. Just i created login form with username and password.... I dont know how to check the entered username and password is present in .txt file.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't use any client side scripting (i.e. javascriptvin a browser) for security. Ever.

Next, don't save your password plaintext in a txt.

If you really want to create a secure login, try out an .htaccess (see this question [Password protecting a directory and all of it's subfolders using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229656/password-protecting-a-directory-and-all-of-its-subfolders-using-htaccess) ) or a php form.
I think an .htaccess would suit you better, as it's much easier to setup and doesn't require any coding.