# htaccess Deny folder and subfolder and subfiles

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

i have a folder and i try to protect it and ALL his content with a password by using a .htaccess file

i know how to protect a file

```
<Files page.php>
AuthName "Message" 
AuthUserFile \www\.htpasswd 
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
</Files>
```

it works perfecly to protect a file

but it doesn't work for a folder !

```
AuthName "Message" 
AuthUserFile "\www\.htpasswd"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

i can try all that i want, the folder is protected but not the subfolders and his subfiles .

for example `/order/3213132/file.txt`

`/order/` is protected but if i write the complete url in my browser i can read the content of `file.txt`

how to protect a folder and ALL his content with a password  without take off the `.txt` extension ?

Comment: http://www.htaccess-guide.com/password-protection/

Comment: Would you post your .htaccess file content?

Comment: this doesn't work,  i have already did the same before @NorrisOduro     i have a folder order the .htacess file is in this folder but the folder is not blocked

Comment: is there someone ?

Comment: This question was already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229656/password-protecting-a-directory-and-all-of-its-subfolders-using-htaccess

Comment: totaly uselesss it doesn't work , subfiles can be read

Comment: i edit my question so maybe better easy to understand my problem

Comment: Are you sure that problem isn't caused by the browser showing you a cached version of the URL instead of re-requesting it from the server?

Comment: yes of course, the problem is not that you said

Comment: You know you only need to enter the credentials once, right? Any requests after that, until you close the browser, are already authenticated and will not need a password.

Comment: yes i know it, but even if i try to access before enter the credentials , it works -_- my folder is not protected