# How to protect a webpage with a password?

Tags: authentication, passwords, .htpasswd

I have a web app with a setting page that I would like to protect with a password so that unless the password is correctly entered the user cannot change any of the settings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Password protecting a directory and all of it's subfolders using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229656/password-protecting-a-directory-and-all-of-its-subfolders-using-htaccess)

Answer (score 2):

To add a password for a page on your website, you’ll need to modify the `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` files on the server. Take a look at [this link](https://www.elated.com/articles/password-protecting-your-pages-with-htaccess/) for the full details.

Basically you need to do these two things:

1. Modify (or add) the special text file on your server called `.htpasswd`, to contain the username and *encrypted* password separated by a colon on a separate line.

If you have SSH access, this can be done automatically using the `htpasswd` utility:

```
htpasswd -c .htpasswd ben
```

Otherwise you can modify/create the file manually, and handcraft the username/password using an online password encryptor. The linked-to site suggests these three:

- [4WebHelp's online .htpasswd encryption tool](http://www.4webhelp.net/us/password.php)
- [Alterlinks .htaccess password generator](http://shop.alterlinks.com/htpasswd/htpasswd.php)
- [htmlite's htpasswd encryption page](http://www.htmlite.com/HTA006a.php)

As an example, for a username of `ben` and a password of `password12345` you would use this line:

```
ben:51CbcBM13fOMo
```

2. Modify (or add) the special text file called `.htaccess`, in the folder where the settings page you want to protect resides, to contain the following:

```
AuthUserFile /full/path/to/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected Settings Page"

<Files "mySettingsPage.html">
  Require valid-user
</Files>
```

Of course, `/full/path/to/.htpasswd` should be replaced with the full path to where the `.htpasswd` file resides on your server.

Likewise, replace `mySettingsPage.html` with your own settings page name.

Note that the `AuthName` string can be changed to suit.

Comment: @Shadow True, sorry about that. But turns out this is a duplicate anyway, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229656/password-protecting-a-directory-and-all-of-its-subfolders-using-htaccess).