# JS or PHP way to password protect a Figma or generic prototype link?

Tags: javascript, php

Ok, bear with me:
I developed a prototype in Protopie ( but can be Figma, Principle, you name it) and I want to protect it with a password. Unfortunately those software can restrict but not create a single use password protection.

So, I'm thinking of embedding the link in a iframe and then add some custom JS to prompt for a password.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Javascript is generally never a good way to apply security as anyone can open up the browser's dev tools and change it in order to bypass your link.

Comment: You can set a password for the folder: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229656/password-protecting-a-directory-and-all-of-its-subfolders-using-htaccess

Comment: I would say that you can do this via a simple proxy server script, which will perform access control by whatever you prefer - a password, IP address, or whatever you see fit, and then proxying requests without disclosing original unprotected URL. Something like [this](https://github.com/jenssegers/php-proxy) - just add your custom access control logic into filter function.