# Method of low-level encryption of section of website

Tags: javascript, web, encryption, lit

I'm looking for a simple method of encrypting a small portion of my personal developer website. I'd like to display my resume directly on the site, but would prefer to protect it with a password so as to prevent those who are not potential employers from viewing it. What is a safe way of doing so while imposing a limited strain on potential employers (e.g. not requiring them to create an account)?

Notably, I will not be including information like my SSN or anything particularly sensitive -- just regular resume info. For this reason, would it be okay to provide all potential employers with the key, and rotating it every month-or-so?

I'm using Lit as a web component tool, but otherwise the site is vanilla JS + html.

Thanks for any guidance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some shared hosting providers offer password protection as part of their package. You could contact your host and see if that's an option.

Otherwise the simplest password protection solution which doesn't require any third party tools would be to update your `.htaccess` file to require a password. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229656/password-protecting-a-directory-and-all-of-its-subfolders-using-htaccess) for examples on setting it up.

Please note, that this should not be considered a completely secure solution, because it's only basic authentication which can be vulnerable to brute force attacks. However it should satisfy your requirement of adding some protection your personal information.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! I read a bit about .htaccess and I think it'd be fairly easy to set up. Just wanted to make sure it was a legitimate way of going about doing this.