How to restrict web users to only download their reports
We have a Linux website running on Apache with thousands of users, and each user should be able to download reports that are stored in a folder specifically intended for their company. There are hundreds of companies. For example, if user David works for the Acme company, David should be able download all files stored in this folder:
https://www.example.com/customer_files/acme
An example file might be:
https://www.example.com/customer_files/acme/monthly_report.txt
Unfortunately, as it currently works, anyone who knows that URL can access the monthly report, no login required. The URL is wide open. The website is written in Perl. How can I restrict access to that folder to specific users, namely the employees of the Acme company? Each company might have hundreds of users.

You need to require the users to login to the website. Then the Perl application can restrict them only to their own folder.

You shouldn't provide direct links to the documents. Downloads should go through a link to a downloader application. It can then check their company name and restrict them. The documents should be stored outside the web root, or use .htaccess to restrict access to it.

If you don't know how to do stuff like this in your application, it would probably be a good idea to install a third-party document management application.

At the extremely simple end of the spectrum of possible solutions, you can just password-protect each directory with a .htaccess file, and then share the credentials with each client:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229656/password-protecting-a-directory-and-all-of-its-subfolders-using-htaccess

So basically, user authentication and authorisation? This is a topic that PhD theses have been written on, so there's no way to answer comprehensively in a single post. I'll try to give you a high-level overview - which means giving you a few keywords and pointers, but you will certainly have to do further research.

There are three major functions in this:

An identity provider (a.k.a. authenticator, SSO server)
An authorisation gateway
The protected service

The identity provider verifies the user's identity (i.e. login information) and their allowed scope (i.e. the resources the user is allowed to access); the authorisation gateway allows or denies access depending on the response from the identity provider; the protected service serves the actual resource.

In the simplest case, all three functions can be handled by a monolithic service. Your singular backend would have a user database with their scope; when a user requests a resource, the server looks up whether the user has permissions, and responds accordingly.
This could be the easiest to implement if the database that stores company-employee data is managed by your Perl service, and you're able and willing to make changes to the Perl code. But it has the disadvantage of poor interoperability and scalability, not to mention you would be reinventing a lot of wheels.
An alternative is to use existing (and separate) components for each of those three functions. Be aware that if you are doing this in an enterprise setting, it's possible that your company already has these infrastructure in place. If they exist, try to integrate with them. If not, here's a software stack I would recommend looking into:

For your identity provider, Keycloak is a common choice. Alternatively, anything that supports OAuth 2 (a modern authorisation protocol) will do.
The authorisation gateway is often accomplished via a plugin or module in your server framework or reserve proxy. You mentioned Apache, so probably something like mod_oauth2.
And the protected service is your existing Perl server, unmodified.


At the end of the day, the best way forward really depends on your exact circumstances and what you wish to accomplish, to what extent. I do not have enough information, nor can I decide for you. But hopefully I've pointed you in the right direction.

Cyqsimon, thanks for your thorough response. I appreciate the time.
